# Android toolbar show as much as possible menu itemes (without title)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Is there any way to customize the Android toolbar to show as much as possible menu items.

Because this is depends on the screen dpi to show number of the items.

So what I'm looking for is to fill as much as possible of the items and for the rest to be in the popup menu.

Comment: Try to add `android:showAsAction="always"` on your menu items which u want to display always.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't need always, I need to fill as much as possible (Fill the space).

Comment: Add ifRoom instead of always

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but this leaves a big space that I can use to show more actions.

Comment: Can u show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

On your menu item use this `android:showAsAction="always"` to show only icons. 
 
 This could land you into few issues so using `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` could be much better if you have less space and more icons to be showcased to the user on the toolbar.And `ifRoom` adjusts automatically if there is space left on the toolbar with various screens as well as with the portrait and landscape views perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't need always, I need to fill as much as possible (Fill the space)